# Directory-specific environment variable

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

I have a directory system like this:

```
|- /root/path
  |- config.json
  |- script1.py
  |- a
    |- script2.py
  |- b
    |- c
      |- d
         |- script3.py
```

`script1.py`, `script2.py`, and `script3.py` both use the "root path" (/root/path) to operate. Right now I have "/root/path" hard coded into the py files. Say, however, I moved or renamed the root path; I would have to go back into all of those scripts and change the root path.

I know one way to 'solve' this is to give the .py files a sense of their relative position, so for example `script3.py` reads from `../../../config.json`. However, at some point this becomes really tedious especially if there's a lot of scripts being set up.

I'm wondering if there's a way of saying "any script that is in this directory that is run *from wherever* will have access to some environment variable". The "from wherever" is italicized because without this restriction I think direnv would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable such as my_root = '/root/path' and define all other paths in your script relative to my_root.  For example,

```
config_json_path = os.path.join(my_root, 'config.json')
```

Comment: This is kind of what I'm doing right now - the issue is that I still have to hard code in my_root = ...

Comment: You have two options - one is to either pass the root_dir as a parameter to the script, or use a environment variable that must be setup before the script is run.